# Extracting and printing each letter from a String only once

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm currently writing an algorithm that takes a user's input, identifies each letter in the entire string, and then prints each letter out along with printing out the number of how many times it appears in that string right next to it. Currently, the algorithm traverses the string and performs the desired actions, but does not group the letters together as shown in the example at the bottom.

I am stuck on what I could do to fix this and would appreciate advice. I am intermediate with Java and chose not to mess with Arrays in this context.

**P.S.** It is designed to exclude spaces.

```
//Algorithm
    String newS2 = "";
    String storage = "";
    int repeated = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<userS.length(); i++){
      if(!userS.substring(i, i + 1).equals(" ") && !(userS.substring(i, i + 1).equals(storage.substring(0)))){
        for(int j = 0; j<userS.length(); j++){
          if(userS.substring(j, j + 1).equals(userS.substring(i, i + 1))){
            storage += userS.charAt(j);
          }
        }
        repeated = storage.length();
        newS2 += storage.charAt(0) + String.valueOf(repeated);
        repeated = 0;
        storage = "";
      }
    }
```

userS is a previously initialized String variable that is set to what the user inputs via a `Scanner` variable.

Currently, if I input "This message", I get: `t1h1i1s3m1e2s3s3a1g1e2` when I really want to get: `t1h1i1s3m1e2g1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not keeping track of letters that have already appeared in your source string, so all the extra stuff in your new String are the additional occurrences of each character with the total number of times that character appears over the remainder of the string.

You need an additional check to see whether you've already encountered a letter. Try using `String.contains()` to exclude duplicate characters. The logic is: if the new string doesn't already contain this character, I should add the character. Otherwise, do nothing.

```
if(!newS.contains(storage.substring(0, 1))
{
    storagestorage += userS.charAt(j);
}
```

You really should be using some sort of data structure, however. Java has data structures for a reason. Try using a HashMap where the single character String is the key and the number of repetitions is the value and you'll have a compact piece of code that's dead easy to follow. Right now, your approach is a bit unintuitive because you're building up `storage` character by character and deriving the repetitions based on how many times that character is stored instead of simply incrementing a counter.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

for(int count = 0; count < userS.length(); count++)
{
    String sub = userS.subString(count, count + 1);

    if(myMap.containsKey(sub))
    {
        // this char is already in the map
        myMap.replace(sub, new Integer(myMap.get(sub) + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        myMap.put(sub, new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

I think that's right, pardon typos as I'm on mobile at the moment.

Comment: This is all super helpful! Sadly, I am not smart enough, nor do I think I am allowed to use data structures as this is supposed to challenge what I have been learning in my Java class recently. I ended up rewriting the algorithm to better identify running into letters the algorithm has already used. The only issue is that I'm now running into IndexOutOfBounds errors and cannot figure out why. I would post my updated code but idk how. Should I just update my question?

Comment: Then forget the part about data structures and just use String.contains as I indicated. I provided both a direct answer to your question and an alternative. You are free to choose either.

Comment: I gave it a shot, which gave me an error that says `Assignment4.java:68: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to CharSequence
else if(!newS2.contains(storage.charAt(1))){
^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error`

Comment: Edited to substitute substring for charAt, which was producing a char rather than the required String. Try it again. Please bear in mind that I can't be your personal uncompensated tutor -- I actually have a paying job. You're going to have to work through some of these small things on your own because that's how you learn. Make the effort to make sure you understand the solution I"m proposing because once you understand the "why" you can understand the "what" and the "how" on your own.

Comment: Understood :) Thank you for all the help! The use of .contains was exactly the method I was looking for. I have only 1 final kink in the hose to work out, and then my algorithm will be fully functioning!

Comment: Not a problem. If the answer helped, click the checkmark to the left so that others will know what worked. And as you can see, while I'm not your tutor, I'm still here, so if you can't work out that final kink, feel free to post a question and I'll take a look. Also, don't say you're not smart enough. You just need to give yourself time to struggle with a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would using some data structures be an option?

In Java you can use a type like LinkedHashMap that preserves the order of entries.

Try this:

```
        Map<Character, Integer> stringCounts = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        String userS = "This message";

        for(int i = 0; i<userS.length(); i++){

            char c = userS.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {   // Ignore Whitespace
                continue;
            }

            stringCounts.putIfAbsent(c, 0);  // Add counter for this character if not there already
            stringCounts.put(c, (stringCounts.get(c) + 1));

        }

        StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
        for( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : stringCounts.entrySet()) {
            bld.append(e.getKey()).append(e.getValue());
        }


        // Printout to check solution
        System.out.println(bld.toString());
```

This produces output:

```
T1h1i1s3m1e2a1g1
```